# Do EventWaitHandle.Set Wake another waiting thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm not to sure about something about EventWaitHandle.Set.
When called from within current thread and there is another thread waiting for the event, do the current thread get to sleep so that other thread gets to run (ASAP)?

I'm asking because in some of my code I have to add some object to a "threads shared" queue and that operation has really to go as quick as possible. But in the other thread where that queue is being used, speed is "not required".
So I'm proceeding like this:

```
        // Speed "not required"
        mailThread = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                MailMessage mail;
                pushMailLockMREvt.WaitOne();
                {
                    if (mails.Count == 0)
                    {
                        mail = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mail = mails.Dequeue();
                    }
                }
                pushMailLockMREvt.Set(); // Does this put current on sleep on lower it's priority??

                if (mail != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MailClient.Send(mail);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exe)
                    {
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mailSem.WaitOne();
                }
            }
        });

        [...]

        // Speed required
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            pushMailLockMREvt.WaitOne(); // ASAP please...
            {
                mails.Enqueue(mailMessage);

                if (mails.Count == 1)
                {
                    mailSem.Set();
                }
            }
            pushMailLockMREvt.Set();
        });
```

Comment: No, the current thread will *not* sleep just because it signals the wait handle. But it may relinquish the rest of its timeslice (that's pretty subtle and low-level and isn't something you should rely on). You should not need to take any special action.

Comment: Then is there any reason I should not just use lock statements instead of the EventWaitHandle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the current thread will not sleep just because it signals the wait handle. But it may relinquish the rest of its timeslice (that's pretty subtle and low-level and isn't something you should rely on). You should not need to take any special action.

It is probably the case that the thread that has just finished waiting *will* get a brief boost in thread priority.

See [this documentation for the Windows API function `SetThreadPriorityBoost()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from which I quote:

> When a thread is running in one of the dynamic priority classes, the system temporarily boosts the thread's priority when it is taken out of a wait state.

Also see [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So the thread that just woke up from the wait should (normally) get a small boost. I'm not totally sure that this also applies to managed threads, but I seem to remember reading somewhere that it does. I can't find the source of that, though.

Comment: Do you suggest I put "Thread.Sleep()" to raise the oods the "speed requiring" thread get its hands on resources?

Comment: Yes, `Thread.Sleep(0)` is a valid thing to do in such circumstances. It explicitly means "relinquish the rest of my current timeslice". Only a parameter value of zero means that - anything larger means to wait for that long as normal.

Comment: However note that the advice *used* to be to [use `Sleep(1)` rather than `Sleep(0)`](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,1c013d42-c983-4102-9233-ca54b8f3d1a1.aspx), however [things have changed since Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that's no longer true. You might still want to use `Thread.Sleep(1)` but you should instrument your build to see if it really helps.